# tasklist to filter by multiple PIDs

Tags: filter, cmd, find, tasklist

I'm using [`tasklist`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) command.

I'm trying to use the `/fi` option to filter multiple PIDs.

#### Attempt

`tasklist.exe /v /fi "PID eq 3248" /fi "PID eq 9488"`

#### Result

`INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.`

This **doesn't work**. I can only assume the filters are evaluated internally using logical-and and obviously would never be true.

#### Question

How to filter by multiple PIDs?

#### Ugly alternative 1

If I run it separately, the result are OK and I can set the process information. However,

- `tasklist.exe /v /fi "PID eq 3248"`
- `tasklist.exe /v /fi "PID eq 9488"`

I'd like to refrain activating two separate commands.

#### Ugly alternative 2

use `find`

```
tasklist.exe /v  | find /i "9488"
```

Which brings the questions:

1. How to I find multiple PIDs?
2. How to make sure the found strings are really the PID and NOT anything else.

Comment: Findstr replaced Find decades ago. `findstr "1234 1238"` would find lines with either number. You can do this query in WMIC but it would be long and ugly. `wmic process where "ProcessID=8152 or ProcessID=3504" get`

Comment: Does WMI give me the `Window Title`? I couldn't find the right `Win32_Process class` property correspond to this attribute

Comment: Ugly alt2 `tasklist.exe /v  | findstr "9488 3248"` but with /v option you could also match mem usage for pids less than 1000

Comment: @LotPings my question remains: `How to make sure the found strings are really the PID and NOT anything else` this number can appear in the `Window Title` column and I don't want to get false positive on this grep.

Comment: All PIDs are multiple of 4. That fact gives you a 75% confidence. Window tile isn't available by WMIC (tasklist gives only ONE window title per process even if there is 100 of them). State your actual problem.

Comment: Even more ugly `tasklist /v /FO csv` check on pid in field2 ev. in a sub. I don't like it myself. Powershell isn't an alternative?

Comment: A principal of programming is programs don't mess with other programs. Therefore Windows gives extremely limited info on this to scripts. Full programs might be a debugger or a Task Manager replacement, or anything so full programs have full access if they want it.

Comment: My real problem is trying to get the window title for each PID base of list of PIDs. I've decided that `tasklist` is the simplest & most robust solution (WMI doesn't always work). Code is written in `JScript`

Comment: Usually the command line which WMIC does can do the same job as window title. WMIC needs to be run by an ADMIN the FIRST time it's run (it stupidly does first run admin only initialisation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tasklist` is not able to filter to several PIDs. So use full output and use another method to filter:

use `csv` as output format; PID is token2, windowtitle is token9.
`findstr` is able to search for more than one string (separated by spaces here).
`/x` checks "complete line", so `45` would not match `3456`.
`>nul` supresses output of `findstr` (we need only the errorlevel, not the actual output)
`&&` acts as "if previous command (findstr) was successful, then..."

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,9 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /v /fo csv') do (
  echo %%~a|findstr /x "3248 9488" >nul && echo %%~a    %%~b
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A powershell solution

```
[regex]$Pid='(75068|6712)'
Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle -and $_.ID -match $Pid} |select ID,MainWIndowtitle
```

Output

```
   Id MainWindowTitle
   -- ---------------
75068 cmd - tasklist to filter by multiple PIDs - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox
 6712 VmUbuntu-1604lts [wird ausgeführt] - Oracle VM VirtualBox
```